# Direct URL to a file in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a CSV file that users downloaded online and saved in a directory on my app. I am trying to create a link to this file so that the user can click the link and the file can be downloaded automatically to their computer. The code below keeps telling file not found. Please does anyone know how to solve this?

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}



{% block main %}
 
<p> <a href="/kaggle_dataset/emmy/IRIS.csv" download> Download File </a> </p>
    
{% endblock main %}
```

Comment: presumably that means file not found ... you probably need to look into having your nginx or apache serve the static files from a kaggle_dataset endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Joran Beasley for your assitance. I changed the directory the file was being served to static and everythong works find now.